# Enable multi size icon support in.desktop file

Tags: linux, unix, ubuntu, desktop, ubuntu-14.04

I created a desktop file with this contents:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Mozilla Firefox - dev
Type=Application
Comment=Web Application
Exec=/usr/lib/firefox/firefox -P dev -no-remote
Icon=/home/noi/Desktop/test.png
```

It's nice it launches Firefox in the right profile as expected. However The Icon is single size. How to make it support multiple sizes?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scalable (SVG) icons, suggested in [lxg's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25513952/673852), are no good when you need sizes on the order of 32x32 pixels. One has to fine-tune raster icons to get them look nice.

If you have an array of icons with different sizes, there's a way to get the correct ones chosen automatically: put them under the same name in directories like `/usr/share/icons/hicolor/${IconSize}/apps/${AppName}.png` (not sure whether it'll work if placed not in `hicolor` dir). Then, at least according to my experience with KDE's Dolphin (and `mimetypes` dir instead of `apps`), the correct icon size is chosen depending on the size needed (and nearest appears to be scaled when exact size is unavailable).

Comment: Thanks very much for this info @Rsulan! What about for Qt based systems? I think your statement is true for GTK based systems right?

Comment: @Noitidart KDE (and thus Dolphin) is already Qt-based, so that was exactly the system I tested this on.

Comment: Ah thank you very much! I verify that this is the same exact situation on Ubuntu 15.01 and 14.02

Answer (score 3):

The `Icon` parameter can either contain an absolute file path, then this file will be used. As far as I know, you can use a rather large file (e.g. 128x128), the Desktop Environment will scale it automatically. These days, you should even be able to use an SVG icon, it should be supported by most DEs.

You can also pass an identifier like `utilities-desktop-extra` or `preferences-desktop-sound`, then the DE will try to find a matching icon within the installed icon sets **in the correct size**. If you want a Firefox icon, you should use `Icon=firefox`, you can be pretty sure that every common icon set does have a Firefox icon, in most cases even one that is nicely integrated with the rest of the icon set.

*source: http://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/ar01s05.html*

Comment: Btw, have a look at `/usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop` on your own box, this should also provide some hints.

Comment: Actually this leads me toanother question. I have created a few icons. 16px, 32, 64, 128. In windows I created an ICO file out of it, so now when icon resizes it automatically takes right size. For linux can I make and apply and icon like this? In OSX we use ICNS file. Should I make another topic for this one?

Comment: Well, you can only use supported image formats, and I think you're restricted to the common ones like PNG, JPEG, GIF or SVG here (sorry, don't know which are actually supported). But all of these don't support multiple images in one file, except maybe GIF, but not in the way you want. I am using Linux since over 11 years now and have fiddled a bit with iconsets myself, but I have never seen icon files containing more than one image. Sure, you can start a new question about that, but then maybe better on the Linux/Unix SE. Or maybe even the freedesktop.org mailing list.

Comment: Thanks for such an in depth reply. If they don't allow multiple sizes in one file, do the default iconsets not have multiple sizes for an icon? Maybe I can append to the iconset and call it `firefox-badged` and then set `Icon=firefox-badged` in `.desktop` file. Reason I ask is because my addon enables badging of different profiles and creating desktop shortcuts. You know what I mean?

Comment: A common icon set consists of folders for sizes, then folders for topics, then png files. E.g `oxygen/48x48/actions/arrow-left.png`. Simply download one, e.g. from kde-look.org/gnome-look.org. You can of course create your logo in different sizes, but you would have a hard time deploying it (write permissions, distro-specific paths, DE-dependent sizes, caching). Also, keep in mind that common icon sets are artworks of thousands of finely designed images, and a third-party icon never integrates well. From my experience, I say, use `Icon=firefox`, and spend your time on more important stuff. ;)

Comment: Haha thanks I think I'll just set it to the single png that's 128px, getting the distro specific paths sounds way too scary haha. Thanks again man really appreciate it.